# Probability of m repetitions when drawing from a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics

When independently drawing $n$ random numbers from the set of positive integers $1, ..., M$ using a uniform distribution, I would like to know the probability of drawing any number $m$ or more times. More specifically, I would like to state a reasonable upper bound for this like

> "I am 99% sure no number will be drawn more than $m$ times"

Obviously, the probability of drawing a single number is $\frac{1}{M}$ and that of drawing a specific number $m$ times would be $\frac{1}{M^m}$, I think. However, I am trying to find the probability of drawing **any** number $m$ times.

Comment: small correction: $0$ is not positive. I took it away in an edit.

Comment: Firstly: the probability of drawing *a specific* number $m$ times is $\dbinom n m \dfrac{(M-1)^{n-m}}{M^n}$

Comment: Secondly: the probability of drawing two specific numbers $m$ times each is $\dbinom n {m,m,n-2m}\dfrac{(M-2)^{n-2m}}{M^n}$ and so on.

Comment: Another observation: any reasonable upper bound should go to $0$ when $m$ is fixed and $n\to \infty$. Also, for $n=m$, you get exactly the $m$-norm (to the power $m$ of your distribution, in this case uniform distribution, $\frac{1}{M^{m-1}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: the probability of drawing *a specific* number $m$ times is: $$\dbinom n m \dfrac{(M-1)^{n-m}}{M^n}$$

Secondly: the probability of drawing two specific numbers $m$ times each is $$\dbinom n {m,m,n-2m}\dfrac{(M-2)^{n-2m}}{M^n}$$

And so on.

Thirdly: Use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.  The probability that some number is drawn exactly $m$ times is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\min\{M,\lfloor n/m\rfloor\}}(-1)^{k-1}\dfrac {M!}{k!(M-k)!}\cdot\dfrac{\;}{\qquad}\cdot\dfrac{}{\qquad}$$

Can you complete?

Comment: Well, now this is a little more complex than I thought. Haven't understood it completely, but I keep on trying. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Too much for a comment:

Let $E_{i}$ denote the event that number $i\in\left\{ 1,\dots,M\right\} $
is drawn at least $m$ times.

Applying inclusion/exclusion we find:

$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{M}E_{i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{M}P\left(E_{i}\right)-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq M}P\left(E_{i}\cap E_{j}\right)+\cdots$$

Applying symmetry we find:

$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{M}E_{i}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{M}\binom{M}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k-1}P\left(E_{1}\cap\cdots\cap E_{k}\right)$$

I have not much hope to finding suitable expressions for $P\left(E_{1}\cap\cdots\cap E_{k}\right)$,
though we do have $P\left(E_{1}\cap\cdots\cap E_{k}\right)=0$ if
$km>n$.