# Drawing $m$ objects from $n$ types (with replacement). What is the distribution of type counts?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am drawing $m$ objects randomly from $n$ types (with replacement). Then I count how many times each type is selected. What is the expected distribution of counts of each type?

More precisely, let $c_k$ be the count of objects of type $k$ (where $k=1\dots n$). What is the probability distribution of $c_k$?

My second question is about the *distribution of counts*. More precisely, let $q_c$ be the number of types that get counted $c$ times:

$$q_c = \sum_{k=1}^n \delta_{c_k,c}$$

where $\delta_{x,y}$ is Kronecker's delta.

What is the expected value of $q_c$?

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688453/probability-of-m-repetitions-when-drawing-from-a-uniform-distribution

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you, I solved it using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am drawing $m$ objects of $n$ types (with replacement). Let $c_{k}$
be the count of objects of type $k$ ($k=1,\dots,n$). We have:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}=m
$$
and the probabilities of counts are given by:

$$
P\left(c_{1},\dots,c_{n}\right)=\frac{m!}{n^{m}}\frac{1}{c_{1}!\dots c_{n}!}
$$
Applying the multinomial theorem, we find that the marginal probability
that $c_{k}=c$ is:

$$p_{k}\left(c\right)=\binom{m}{c}\frac{\left(n-1\right)^{m-c}}{n^{m}}$$

and it follows that $\left\langle c_{k}\right\rangle =m/n$. Let $q_{c}$
be the number of types that get selected $c$ times:
$$
q_{c}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\delta_{c_{k},c}
$$
By noting that $\left\langle \delta_{c_{k},c}\right\rangle =p_{k}\left(c\right)$,
we find:
$$
\left\langle q_{c}\right\rangle =\binom{m}{c}\frac{\left(n-1\right)^{m-c}}{n^{m-1}}
$$